# Firefox hangs when using developer tools

Tags: debugging, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I am getting a little desperate here: Almost every time I try to use the Firefox browser tools (FF 66.0.3 on Mac, but has been the same in previous versions) to inspect an element, when selecting any page element to show its code in the inspector, the inspector switches to the javascript debugger, marks an error in the `jquery.min.js` file (complete first line of three) and causes the browser to hang, i.e. I can still scroll the window, but more or less nothing else (for example no reload, no clicking a link would work etc.)

The debugger shows `Error: Permission denied to access property "nodeName"`. I am doing nothing special, I just use the inspector and try to select any element on the page.

The crazy thing is that this happens on *most* websites, even here on Stackoverflow, so I suppose some particular browser setting must cause this.

I know this is a vague description and therefore a bit off-topic, but I'd be very grateful for any hints how I could fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably have the "Pause on exceptions" and "Pause on caught exceptions" options set to on:

[image: screenchot of the debugger panel]

These will cause the debugger to pause javascript execution whenever an exception is thrown, even though the exception has been caught e.g by a try catch block, like many test codes use.

You can un-toggle these to enjoy a more natural experience or click the play icon to resume the javascript.

Comment: Yes, that's it - thank you very much! I just wonder why something in the "official" jquery.min.js file throws an exception like this?...

Comment: Well for instance the one in my screenshot is a test to see if the browser supports basics CSS pseudo selectors, if it didn't, then there wouldn't have been any error thrown.